# Bootstrap range slider class name in JS

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a bootstrap Range Slider with the text below as percentage. I need help with the JS code where presently it is calling the HTML element as the document.getEelementByID

I want the same thing to happen but with document.getElementByClassName as there will be many input field in my project. Below is the following code

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("percent");
output.innerHTML = slider.value; // Display the default slider value

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
slider.oninput = function() {
    output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

```html
<input  type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50"  id="myRange" >
      <span id="percent"></span>
```

Comment: change the input `id`s and span `id`s and add oninput event listener to every element.

Comment: so for example `money-range` and `money-percent` etc.

Comment: Sorry I am not that good in JS can you please send me the code

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping each input and its neighbouring span in a wrapping div. This will allow you to loop through each input and a span that corresponds to the current wrapping div.

See the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LmjdoX) for the full solution.

Here is the JS I used:

```
    var sliderWrappers = document.getElementsByClassName('slider-wrapper');


for(var i = 0; i < sliderWrappers.length; i++) {

    var slider = sliderWrappers[i].childNodes[1];
    var sliderOutput = sliderWrappers[i].childNodes[3];

    sliderValue(slider, sliderOutput);

}

function sliderValue(slider, sliderOutput) {
    sliderOutput.innerHTML = slider.value;
    slider.oninput = function() {
        sliderOutput.innerHTML = this.value;
    }
}
```

You can then get the specific value of any slider by targeting it's unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
    var output = document.getElementsByClassName("percent");
    update();
    
    slider.oninput = function() {
      update();
    }
    function update() {
      var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(output);
      for (var el of arr) {
        el.innerHTML = slider.value;
      }
    }
```

```html
<input  type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50"  id="myRange" >
<span class="percent"></span>
<span class="percent"></span>
<span class="percent"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you two solutions to the problem.

## Quick and dirty

Assume the slider and the output are always besides each other in the dom. You could use some logic to look up the input element before the label:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".percent")).forEach(output => {
    var slider = output.previousElementSibling;
    slider.addEventListener("input", update);
    update();
    function update() {
        output.innerText = slider.value;
    }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50">
  <span class="percent"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50">
  <span class="percent"></span>
</div>
```

## Reusable, component based approach

If you think about it, you are basically developing a new component, a "labelled slider". There are many frameworks out ther that let you defining your own component, like Angular, Vue, React, Polymer, etc.. (the list is much, much longer than I just showed you).

For simplicity, let's see a standard way using Web Components.

```js
class LabeledSlider extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const template = document.getElementById("template-labeled-slider");
    this.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    this._attach();
    this._update();
  }
  get inputElement() { return this.querySelector("input"); }
  get textElement() { return this.querySelector("span"); }
  _update() {
    this.textElement.innerText = this.inputElement.value;
  }
  _attach() {
    this.inputElement.addEventListener("input", () => this._update());
  }
}

window.customElements.define('labeled-slider', LabeledSlider);
```

```html
<div><labeled-slider/></div>
<div><labeled-slider/></div>

<template id="template-labeled-slider">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50">
  <span></span>
</template>
```